# Obtain the first business weekday of the NEXT month

Tags: sql-server-2016

I'm trying to derive a date field that represents the first business day (in this case, it means the first weekday - also excluding holidays) of the next month.  I was able to derive the first day of the next month, using the following:

```
SET @strFirstOfNextMonth = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DATEADD(MM, 0, GETDATE())), 0), 112))
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually should have said "Weekday" and not "Business Day".

Comment: Please put that important information concerning the question into the question itself!

Comment: Please edit the question with more complete and accurate requirements. If people who have been here for a long time ask for more info, you’re not getting “skewered,” you’re being gently guided how to ask better, more complete questions up front, that don’t require a dozen follow-up questions for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @strFirstOfNextMonth datetime;

select @strFirstOfNextMonth = 
                        case when datepart(dw, dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate()))) = 1
                            then dateadd(day, 2, eomonth(getdate()))
                            else case when datepart(dw, dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate()))) = 7
                                    then dateadd(day, 3, eomonth(getdate()))
                                    else dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate()))
                                end
                        end;
select @strFirstOfNextMonth, convert(varchar, @strFirstOfNextMonth, 112);
```

Comment: This assumes your datepart function is configured according to return Sunday as 1.

Comment: What about public holidays?

Comment: i believe the poster changed it to weekday.

Comment: OK - well, my understanding is that the OP wants the first business day of the following month - and this will mean the exclusion of public holidays (1st of May springs to mind!). Basically, there is a requirement for a calendar table as @AaronBetrand says (he's rarely wrong!).